# C# handling the resizing of dynamically created picture boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, picturebox

With the following piece of code, I am dynamically creating and displaying picture boxes based on the number of screens I select in the combo box like in the bellow image:

---

[image]

---

This seems to work great, but the issue comes when i expand the application size, then the picture boxes dont expand correctly, like in the image bellow:

---

Enlarging the app:

### [image]

Reducing the size of the app:

### [image]

### Here is the Method:

```
 private void CreatePictureBoxes(int num)
        {
            panelCameras.Controls.Clear();

            int spacing = 2;
            int numRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)num / 2);

            int pbWidth = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (3 * spacing)) / 2;
            int pbHeight = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - ((numRows + 1) * spacing)) / numRows;

            if (num == 1)
            {
                pbWidth = panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (2 * spacing);
                pbHeight = panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - (2 * spacing);
            }
            else if (num == 2)
            {
                pbWidth = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (2 * spacing)) / 2;
                pbHeight = panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - (2 * spacing);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.BackColor = Color.Black;
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pb.Dock = DockStyle.None;
                pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                pb.Location = new Point((i % 2) * (pbWidth + spacing) + spacing, (i / 2) * (pbHeight + spacing) + spacing);

                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
                lbl.ForeColor = Color.White;
                lbl.AutoSize = false;
                lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                pb.Controls.Add(lbl);

                panelCameras.Controls.Add(pb);

                pb.Size = new Size(pbWidth, pbHeight);
                pb.Dock = DockStyle.None;
                pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;

                
            }
        }
```

---

My best attempt to fix this was to create an additional Method to handle the expansion of the app and call it at the end of the end of the `CreatePictureBoxes` method :

---

```
private void pb_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox? pb = sender as PictureBox ?? null;

            if (pb != null)
            {
                int spacing = 10;
                int numRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)panelCameras.Controls.Count / 2);

                int pbWidth = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (3 * spacing)) / 2;
                int pbHeight = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - ((numRows + 1) * spacing)) / numRows;

                if (panelCameras.Controls.Count == 1)
                {
                    pbWidth = panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (2 * spacing);
                    pbHeight = panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - (2 * spacing);
                }
                else if (panelCameras.Controls.Count == 2)
                {
                    pbWidth = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (2 * spacing)) / 2;
                    pbHeight = panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - (2 * spacing);
                }

                pb.Size = new Size(pbWidth, pbHeight);
                pb.Location = new Point((pb.TabIndex % 2) * (pbWidth + spacing) + spacing, (pb.TabIndex / 2) * (pbHeight + spacing) + spacing);
            }
        }
```

---

This somehow worked but I believe will cause more issues down the  line and I dont believe it to be a good approach.

Would anyone know how I could handle the picture boxes sizes to be relative to the size of the application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, use [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), set at design time the `SizeType` of the columns and rows  to share the space equally, dock fill your pboxes in 2x2-grid cells, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks @dr.null Would what Jiri said in their response be the appropriate answer or would you know a better solution?

Comment: The accepted answer is a direct solution for the problem that you brought. So, it's accepted to me. However, you don't need to do this in the first place, the WinForms layout controls exist for a reason, mainly to avoid doing what you are doing here. A better solution or the right approach is to using a layout panel, specifically the suggested one in my first comment.

Comment: [Position and layout of controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-7.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the creation and the laying out of panels, like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // ...

    panelCameras.Layout += panelCameras_Layout;
}

private void CreatePictureBoxes(int num)
{
    panelCameras.Controls.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.BackColor = Color.Black;
        pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pb.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        lbl.ForeColor = Color.White;
        lbl.AutoSize = false;
        lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        pb.Controls.Add(lbl);

        panelCameras.Controls.Add(pb);
    }
}

protected void panelCameras_Layout(object? sender, LayoutEventArgs levent)
{
    var num = panelCameras.Controls.Count;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        int spacing = 2;
        int numRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)num / 2);

        int pbWidth = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (3 * spacing)) / 2;
        int pbHeight = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - ((numRows + 1) * spacing)) / numRows;

        if (num == 1)
        {
            pbWidth = panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (2 * spacing);
            pbHeight = panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - (2 * spacing);
        }
        else if (num == 2)
        {
            pbWidth = (panelCameras.ClientSize.Width - (2 * spacing)) / 2;
            pbHeight = panelCameras.ClientSize.Height - (2 * spacing);
        }

        var pb = panelCameras.Controls[i];
        pb.Location = new Point((i % 2) * (pbWidth + spacing) + spacing, (i / 2) * (pbHeight + spacing) + spacing);
        pb.Size = new Size(pbWidth, pbHeight);
    }
}
```

Note that I removed setting the Size and Location from CreatePictureBoxes and I also removed changing the Anchor style!

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help! This seems to work perfectly. I just have one question. Would this be a correct approach to handle this or would you believe there is a better alternative

Comment: It depends. Usually, there are many ways, and choosing one is always a challenge :) so don't worry. If you need to reuse the behavior, you can derive your own control (let's say, from the Panel), and override OnLayout. Often you realize the solution already exists - perhaps you could use the TableLayoutPanel. But if this works well for you, use it. You can always change it if you need to.